# Adding Objects with multiple attributes

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out if there's a better way to get the same outcome from this line of code. For instance: defining a new object (c3) inside of the add_coordinates function if possible? Or is this the simplest and most effective way to add the two objects.

```
class Values:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
    def add_values(self,x,y):
        self.x=x+self.x
        self.y=y+self.y
       
c1 = Values(5,6)
c2 = Values(7,9)
c3= Values(0,0)


c3.add_values(c1.x,c1.y)
c3.add_values(c2.x,c2.y)

print(c3.x)
print(c3.y)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One improvement would be to override the `__iadd__` dunder method so that you can use `+=`, rather than using a custom function that does essentially the same thing:

```py
class Values:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
        
    def __iadd__(self, other):
        return Values(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)

c1 = Values(5,6)
c2 = Values(7,9)
c3= Values(0,0)


c3 += c1
c3 += c2

print(c3.x)
print(c3.y)
```

This prints:

```
12
15
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define the `__add__` function to leverage the `+` operator

```
class Values:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Values(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)
```

then for example

```
>>> c1 = Values(5,6)
>>> c2 = Values(7,9)
>>> c3 = c1 + c2
>>> c3.x
12
>>> c3.y
15
```